# m Input and n Output Neural Network

Tags: r

I am new to R and am planning to use R for a Artificial Neural Network regression. I have 10 different scenarios for each observation (Input). For each scenario, there are 7 variables, which means 7 output. I have 1000 observations in total and I do have 1000 expected output.I want to use 800 observations for training and the rest for testing. Could any one provide a sample for my case? I don't quite understand the instructions from the packages. Appreciated.

Comment: example with iris in [here](http://www.parallelr.com/r-deep-neural-network-from-scratch/)

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://www.jeffheaton.com/2013/06/basic-classification-in-r-neural-networks-and-support-vector-machines/), it's very similar to your task.
Briefly: taken a [standart dataset](http://www.heatonresearch.com/wiki/Iris_Data_Set) and obtaining training and test datasets

```
irisTrainData = sample(1:150,100)
irisValData = setdiff(1:150,irisTrainData)
```

the neural network may be trained and used for prediction next way:

```
library(nnet)
ideal <- class.ind(irisdata$species)
irisANN = nnet(irisdata[irisTrainData,-5], ideal[irisTrainData,], size=10, softmax=TRUE)
predict(irisANN, irisdata[irisValData,-5], type="class")
```

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.